# How do I set traps in the kitchen ceiling when my roof is flat and I lack access?

Tags: pest-control, mice

At night we can hear mice scuttling about over the kitchen.  This area of the house has a flat roof above it, and a solid drywall ceiling with no access to the space between the ceiling and the roof.  There is no evidence that the mice have gotten below into the kitchen, but I suspect that it's just a matter of time before they do.

How do I set traps when I can't put the traps where the mice are?  Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Well, it was becoming enough of a problem that we decided not to DIY and called a professional.  Turns out they are "roof rats"  http://www.maricopa.gov/EnvSvc/VectorControl/RR/RRInfo.aspx  Curiously a recommendation from that site is to set bait traps high in the citrus trees.  Not a place I would have thought of.

Answer (score 4):

Although you cannot access the area between the ceiling and roof, you should certainly give all due effort to finding possible point(s) of entry for the mice. For one thing, you can bait or place traps nearby (trial and error here might also help to identify whether or not your hunches are right about points-of-entry).

More importantly, trapping the mice will have limited benefit if you can't cut off access to other mice.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some sort of access, otherwise the mice couldn't get in there. Stands to reason.

Therefore, you need to find the access. Probably where the flat roof joins with a pitched roof or deck pergola there is access under eaves or similar.

Put your baited traps there.